# CSRF - same browser multiple instances of app

Tags: php, csrf

opened browser and enter URL of admin and logged in successfully, went to a inner page called announcements and added a new announcement. Opened a notepad write miscellaneous html page with form action and with hidden field to delete the added announcement and hidden CSRF token which I can know from the already opened browser tab. Next in the same browser opened new tab and opened the miscellaneous html page with submit and this deleted the added announcement since the CSRF token is matched. how to prevent this? I done this using PHP 5.

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Comment: yes, please update your answer.

Comment: Could you please detail how I should expand it to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to prevent this - an attacker won't be able to read the CSRF token from the current user's session - CSRF tokens should be tied to each user session. It should not be possible for a CSRF token to be used in a session other than that from which it was generated.

Any implementation that does not do this is flawed.